# how to configure postgres not to show not null constraint error

Tags: postgresql, constraints, notnull, openbravo

I'm installing openbravo. The install log shows a heap of SQL errors which are all "not null" constraints errors.

I already searched quite a while for how to fix this, but they only say how to drop the not null constraint in a single table.

What I want is to configure the PostgreSQL server to run in a loosen state which doesn't complain the "not null" at all. I know there is an option for MySQL, but I don't know what is it for PostgreSQL.

---

**Update:** I have eliminated the install error by unchecking "install sample data"' option. What a hard and simple fix!

Comment: I'm gonna guess the real issue is the app trying to insert a NULL instead of DEFAULT.  But we don't have enough context to really know.  glad your fix worked, or at least works for now.

Answer (score 1):

> i know there is an option for mysql, dont know what is it for postgres

Contrary to MySQL the PostgreSQL server does not offer a way to shred your data in such a simple way. Your only chance is to remove the `NOT NULL` constraints from your tables.

BTW: If the constraints are not important - as you say - why are they there at all?

Comment: yes, constraints are necessary. but what i want to fix, is just to make openbravo successly installed.  but the software just breaks itself from the inside during installing. which showed a lot of not null errors. what i got is the same as this guy "Snaketails" got in here :http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-501339-start-25.html

Comment: @user1019877: You might be able to get a list of all NOT NULL columns from the information schema, remove all the NOT NULL constraints (except on PKs!), and then put them all back after your installation.

Answer (score 1):

You can't to do it. There are no any global switch that allows a "loosen state"